# Want to concatenate elements of array into single element

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, concatenation

I have an array of arrays that looks like

```
time 
array([array([   0,    1,    0,   10,   12, 2011], dtype=int16),
   array([   0,    1,    0,   10,   12, 2011], dtype=int16),
   array([   0,    1,    0,   10,   12, 2011], dtype=int16), ...,
   array([   0,   59,   23,   10,   12, 2011], dtype=int16),
   array([   0,   59,   23,   10,   12, 2011], dtype=int16),
   array([   0,   59,   23,   10,   12, 2011], dtype=int16)],
  dtype=object)
```

and I would like to transform this into something like

```
time 
array([0:1:0 10-12-2011,
      etc
      0:59:23 10-12-2011])
```

I feel like I should be able to do this for the whole structure without having to loop through each individual row/column.

Comment: What is `0:1:0 10-12-2011`? Is it a string?

Comment: I want to convert to datetime eventually so I would say yes.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you cannot avoid loops, but you can get a pretty decent result by looping through the outer array and converting your data into `datetime` objects. Let's say `a` is your array:

```
from datetime import datetime
results = array([datetime(*row[::-1]) for row in a])
```